# Collapse header with dynamic height on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a layout where the Header is sticky at the top and i can collapse it when scrolling. I am running into an issue where the as i start scrolling the header collapses and the scroll position is reset to 0 which makes the header expand and this happens many times per second until i actually scroll further.

I am building an Angular2 app and one of the key points is that my header has dynamic height. I've seen a lot of examples where i can set the header `position: fixed` and set a `margin-top: $headerHeight` for the `content`, but this will not work for me due to the fact the header has a dynamic height. Another alternative which i was considering is to just make the content scrollable but i like the behavior where the you can start scrolling even on the header as it would take almost half of the viewport height in my app initially. if it makes a difference I am using CSS grid and flexbox in the project, so just supporting modern browsers.

I've made a codepen to reproduce and illustrate the issue: 
https://codepen.io/darko1002001/pen/eXKYGM

**SCSS**

```
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 200px;
  transition: min-height .2s;
  &.collapsed {
    min-height: 100px;
  }
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header" class="header">Header</div> 
    <div id="content" class="content">Content</div> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    document.getElementById("header").className = "header collapsed";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").className = "header";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a better solution to this. The proposed solution works great in chrome but the behavior is not great in Firefox and Safari for example. There seems to be an easy fix for this in chrome, I found it while digging into the bug reports.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=734461

The solution of adding `overflow-anchor: none;` to the content element in this case works like a charm in Chrome, doesn't cause issues in Safari and Firefox. no Javascript for scrolling is required.

```
.content {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-anchor: none;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed beautiful. Never knew of overflow-anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to -

```
function myFunction() {
 if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
  if(!document.getElementById("header").classList.contains('collapsed')){
      document.documentElement.scrollTop += 100;
      document.getElementById("header").className = "header collapsed";
    }

   } else {
    if(document.getElementById("header").classList.contains('collapsed')){
      document.getElementById("header").className = "header";
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

You should trigger collapse when scrollTop is more than collapsed header height. In this case it's 100px.  If scrollTop is above 100px and header is collapsed, then do nothing. Otherwise, add collapsed to header and scrollTop to +100 to retain its scroll Position. There is still a very tiny skipping when you scroll down, and that is because of transition on height.

Codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VRdYoM

Comment: scrolling the content as i collapse it does indeed solve the problem. I am able to measure the height of the collapsing element and add its height to the scroll. The content jumps but i think the result is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
.content {
    max-height:200px;
    overflow:scroll;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}
```